# Svn move with wild card

Tags: svn, shell

The following command does not work on linux shell

```
svn move *.jpg imagedirectory/
```

it gave me an error:

```
svn: Client error in parsing arguments
```

Is there another way to achieve the same result?  I want to batch svn move files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.jpg;
do svn move $i imagedirectory;
done
```

Is probably what i'd do.

either that, or something with find and -exec